# How to change path in getcwd() function

Tags: php

I am using the following code to upload images to pic directory...

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], getcwd() . '/templates/images/pics/' . $pic_name . $ext);

echo getcwd(); //returns C:\wamp\www\sapp\Admin
```

The code simply uploads images inside templates of the Admin folder, not in root. How can I change above code so it could save images into C:\wamp\www\sapp/templates/images/pics/ instead of C:\wamp\www\sapp\Admin/templates/images/pics/. I hope you got idea. thanks..

Answer (score 4):

You can use a relative path to go up one directory with `..`:

```
$pics_path = realpath(getcwd() . '/../templates/images/pics/');
```

I am using [`realpath()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/realpath) here to convert it back to an absolute path like you have asked for. It will also change the directory separators (`/`) to be the correct Windows compatible ones (`\`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `../` to go up a directory:

```
getcwd() . '/../templates/images/pics/' . $pic_name . $ext
```

Comment: How to down 1 level ? is it possible with getcwd() ?